# Mosquito and other ESF top speeds?

Tags: planetside-2

What is the top speed of a mosquito with maxed racer frame, and how does that compare with other ESF w/ max racer frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Mosquito :
>
> - 219 KMPH with just W
> - 247 with W and space
> - 329 w Afterburner
>
> Reaver :
>
> - 199 with W
> - 217 with W and space
> - 352 w Afterburner
>
> Scythe:
>
> - 200 with W
> - 226 with W and space
> - 322 w Afterburner

Gotten from this video:

[ESF speed testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=JXYSvNlnGmA#!)

Comment: Note that the Racer Frame also increases the afterburner speed. A Reaver can actually outrun a Mosquito if both constantly use the afterburner since the Reaver Afterburner is a lot stronger. I assume the Scythe is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @dbemerlin That is true I will add the afterburner speeds aswell

Comment: does anyone have the figures for upgraded racer / hover airframes?

Comment: A recent patch changed the velocity on all ESF racer airframe upgrades. Recommend updating this answer.